# Orientation changes in second UIWindow

Tags: ios, objective-c, orientation, uiwindow

I've added a second `UIWindow` to my application due to an issue that prevents me from displaying the content in the main `UIWindow`. I understand this is not recommended, but I am kind of forced down this route.

Anyway, I've created the second `UIWindow` but I am now trying to set it up to respond to orientation changes as it does not do this automatically, unlike the main window. The problem is I have little experience with iOS specific coding and I am at a bit of a loss with regard to this.

This is what I have got so far:

```
// Create the new UIWindow
mWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, size.height, size.width)];
mWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar + 1.0f;
[mP3NMoreGamesWindow setRootViewController:mMyViewController];
```

MyViewController orientation specific functions:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations.
    NSString * supported_orientation = [Utilities GetDeviceOrientation];
    if ([supported_orientation isEqualToString:@"landscape"] && (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight))
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else if ([supported_orientation isEqualToString:@"portrait"] && (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
                                                                     interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown))
    {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    //returns true if want to allow orientation change
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    NSString * supported_orientation = [Utilities GetDeviceOrientation];
    if ([supported_orientation isEqualToString:@"landscape"])
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    }
    else
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}
```

Is there something I am missing? I was under the impression that the `rootviewcontroller` of a Window receives the orientation change notifications?

Also, is it possible to set the orientation of a `UIWindow` on creation? For example, if the current orientation is landscape when I create the `UIWindow`, can I set the `UIWindowfi` to be landscape and not portrait which it is by default?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is in the app delegate. You can handle supported orientations for every window separately, there:

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
   // check, which window is asking and return the mask
   return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am not sure what exactly you are trying to accomplish, so I could be a tad off-base. However, take a look at your delegate methods:

```
    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:

(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations.
    NSString * supported_orientation = [Utilities GetDeviceOrientation];
    if ([supported_orientation isEqualToString:@"landscape"] && (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight))
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else if ([supported_orientation isEqualToString:@"portrait"] && (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
                                                                     interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown))
    {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    NSString * supported_orientation = [Utilities GetDeviceOrientation];
    if ([supported_orientation isEqualToString:@"landscape"])
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    }
    else
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}
```

Make sure they are actually being called with some breakpoints. My guess is that they are not.

Take a look at this: http://shaune.com.au/using-multiple-uiwindows-in-ios-applications/

Given all of that, the best course would be to setup Notifications using NSNotificationCenter to notify your second window when the first one will rotates and deal with the rotation manually.

Comment: After checking and those functions are been called when it rotates. I think the actual problem is that the new UIWindow is not taking the current orientation into account when I set it up. For example, the app is in the landscape mode when the second UIWindow is created, but the UIWindow created is implicitly set to Portrait. Is it possible to directly set the orientation of a window on creation?